# Remarks using Changes Package

Tags: macros, changes

Using the `changes` package, how can I create a 'remark', which is displayed in the same markup colour formatting, and included in the list of changes when in draft or normal mode, but is removed completely when in final mode.

I wish to decorate a working paper for submission to journal, addressing reviewers comments in such a way that the remarks are removed completely when the final version is compiled.

In other words, I might want to annotate somewhere saying like:

> The above figure has been modified in accordance with reviewers
>   recommendation number XYZ.

This annotation is not relevant to the final document, and is only included in the *draft* so that the editor can see very clearly that the reviewers comments have been *explicitly addressed*.

So If I put the following in the preamble:

```
\usepackage{changes}
\definechangesauthor[name={Nick Hamilton}, color=red]{nh}
```

I can markup newly added content, deleted content, or replaced contend

```
This is \added[id=nh,remark={has to be in it}]{new} text.
This is \deleted[id=nh,remark=obsolete]{unnecessary}text.
This is \replaced[id=nh]{nice}{bad} text.
```

In the above, when the document is in draft mode, these changes will be rendered in 'red' according to the `definechangesauthor` definition above. The content will be markedup when in draft mode, and rendered as usual when in final mode.

I am really after another macro which renders in markup (just like above) when in draft mode, and is omitted completely when in final mode.

Comment: Many Wet Eels http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3343/what-makes-a-good-mwe

Comment: @AFeldman, sure, perhaps the solution below suffices to your standards.

Comment: I'm glad you found the answer to your own question(s).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution, if anyone is interested:

```
\documentclass{article}

%Packages
\usepackage{ifdraft}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{changes}    

%Define Track Changes Author, and Color
\definechangesauthor[name={Nick Hamilton}, color=red]{nh}

%New 'Remark' command
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\Changes@Markup@Remark}[1]{\textbf{NOTE TO ED.:} #1}
\newcommand{\remark}[2][\@empty]{%
    \ifoptionfinal{}{
        \setkeys{Changes@added}{#1}%
        \Changes@output%
            {\Changes@Markup@Remark{#2}}%
            {#2}%
            {\Changes@added@id}%
            {\Changes@added@remark}%
            {#2}%
            {\changesaddname}%
            {\Changes@added@dec}%
            {\Changes@added@decid}%
            {\Changes@added@decremark}%
        \stepcounter{Changes@AddCount\Changes@added@id}%
    }
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]\added[id=nh]{This is some new content}%
\deleted[id=nh]{, Content to Remove}, and %
\replaced[id=nh]{replaced}{original} content. %
\remark{As requested in initial review}

\end{document}
```

**In DRAFT mode**, the following results:

[image: Draft]

**In FINAL mode**, the following results:

[image: Final]